# Is it possible to implement a scrollspy with only javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to implement a scroll-spy to change the active state of buttons in the navigation bar. There are examples that use jQuery but I want to implement it with pure javascript. Is it possible? If it is possible, can you provide me an example code?

Edit: What I mean with pure js is not using any external libraries. Sorry for misrepresenting.

Comment: *Note*: jQuery is JavaScript, native JS can do anything jQuery can do because jQuery is just a library.

Comment: jQuery is nothing more than "JavaScript that has been written by other people", so yes, obviously it is possible. You can always look at the jQuery source code (or just google for equivalents of specific jQuery methods that the example code you have found uses). (That's assuming by "pure JavaScript" you mean "JavaScript + the C code that provides extra APIs that are built into browsers")

Comment: Here's a library for node.js, I don't see it however why it shouldn't work in plain js - just remove `module.exports = ScrollSpy;`:  https://github.com/makotot/scrollspy/blob/master/src/js/modules/scrollspy.js

Comment: I meant without using external libraries. I couldn't find any examples with native JS.

Answer (score 0):

You can just define an handler for the `scroll` event with

```
document.getElementById("mydiv").onscroll = function(event){
    update_buttons();
};
```

Comment: How will I know which element in that div is on screen to make it active?